# Google Apps Script mysteriously stops functioning in for loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a system to copy data from one sheet to another sheet (On a different spreadsheet). It works well, until it is supposed to copy the data. Afterward, it does nothing. No error is thrown, but no alert boxes pop up in the `for` loop. Here is my code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById('13x7AvyYTaocCVBxVZ3ckBjzgxcZfjg9RYM1cE_0VNbU');
  var sheets = master.getSheets();
  var test = DriveApp.createFile('Test', 'fetching user data...');
  var name = test.getOwner().getName();
  test.setTrashed(true);
  var add = true;
  for (var i = 0, n; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    n = sheets[i];
    if (n.getName() == name) {
      add = false;
      updateSheet(n, name);
    }
  }
  if (add) {
    newSheet(master, name);
  }
}

function updateSheet(m, name) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var nr = range.getNumRows();
  var nc = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= nr.length; i++) {
    for (var n = 1, s; n <= nc.length; n++) {
      s = range.getCell(i, n);
      m.getRange(i, n).getCell(1, 1).setValue(s.getValue());
    }
  }
}

function newSheet(master, name) {
  var m = master.insertSheet(name);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var nr = range.getNumRows();
  var nc = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= nr.length; i++) {
    for (var n = 1, s; n <= nc.length; n++) {
      s = range.getCell(i, n);
      m.getRange(i, n).getCell(1, 1).setValue(s.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

I have searched the code, but can't find anything wrong.

Comment: You can track how your code executed by selecting in Apps Script editor menu: View - Execution transcript

Comment: "Execution succeeded" after it hits the `getNumColumns`

Comment: It seems to stop for no reason when it sees the `for`

Comment: Try the Google Apps Script editor debugger and set some Logger.log or console.log to see if your variables are getting the right values. Ref. [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: @Rubén I did. I even checked execution transcript:

...

[18-05-18 17:06:57:672 PDT] Range.getNumRows() [0 seconds
]
[18-05-18 17:06:57:672 PDT] Range.getNumColumns() [0 seconds]

[18-05-18 17:06:57:674 PDT] Execution succeeded [1.656 seconds total runtime]

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms What Logger.logs you included on your code? What were the values of the iterators when the loops stopped? Please consider to create a demo spreadsheet including sample data in order to help others to run your code without having to guess the input data.

Comment: You cannot use a simple trigger to perform things that require authorization - like opening a different workbook. You need an installed trigger to do that.

Comment: @Rubén It never reached the for loop. It stopped before then, right after the `range.getNumColumns()` function. It does this with any sample data.

Comment: @tehhowch It works fine. It opens the other workbook without errors.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms What is the value of nr.length?

Comment: By the way, `onEdit` is a reserved function name. Every edit made by an user will trigger it, but as simple triggers can't run services that require authorization it will throw an error .

Comment: @Rubén Okay, I will change it. But it runs fine, it's the for loop not running that I need help with

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms When you change the name and use an installed trigger, do you receive the same issues? When you add `console.log` statements and log every variable along with a message, e.g. `console.log({message: &quot;checked row and column count&quot;, rows: nr, cols: nc, f: &quot;updateSheet&quot;, ... });` do you find anything strange? Does Stackdriver log anything unexpected? (Also note your `updateSheet` function is terribly inefficient - you can use a single batch read and write to do the same thing in a fraction of the time.

Answer (score 1):

On google documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname, it says ...

```
insertSheet(sheetName)
```

Inserts a new sheet into the spreadsheet with the given name. **The new sheet becomes the active sheet.**

In your code

```
function newSheet(master, name) {
  var m = master.insertSheet(name);  // after calling this function m becomes the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // you've assigned m to sheet
```

I would recommend using getSheetByName('SheetName').

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName");
```

Refer to this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

Answer (score 1):

## The obvious answer (Thanks @Rubén)

In the `for` loop, it says `nc.length` and `nr.length`. Both `getNumRows` and `getNumColumns` return numbers. Since these are *integers*, `.length` is not necessary.